# Why does my Google Cast sender not find my receiver?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

I have an existing Google Cast app.  It's been quite a while since I've touched it because it's been working just fine, but now I want to add some features to it so I'm digging back in.

I've created a second Google Cast app in the Google Cast SDK Developer Console (https://cast.google.com/u/0/publish/#/applications) so I can do some testing without interrupting people using the existing app.  This new one has basically all the same settings: it's a Custom Receiver and it points to a URL -- very simple.  The only difference is that the new URL is my test server instead of our production server.  It's published.

When I run my sender in my test environment and leave the app ID as the existing app, everything works fine. Chrome prompts me to chose a destination device and my Chromecast shows up in there.

Now when I change the app ID in sender code to the new app ID, Chrome says

> No cast destinations found.

I change it back to the original app ID and it finds my Chromecast again no problem.

So, I assume that behind the scenes something is wrong with the configuration of my new app ID but I don't know how to figure out what's wrong.  Additionally, I can watch the logging on the test server and I can see that nothing is hitting my server, so I don't believe Google is making a request to my new URL.

I'm just not really sure where to start to try to figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the serial number you entered in the Google Cast Developer console. It is very easy to get the number wrong. Also, restart your cast device to force it to sync with the servers that track the developer device registrations.